ggplot: How to merge two legend boxes and give legend keys any desired order?
I am trying to make a plot with a few stacked bars and a dot (corresponding to their sum). However, I am having troubles giving the legend keys the positions I want. In particular, I have two questions:

How do I get the legend for the dots to be in the same box as the legend for the bars?
How do I rearrange the order of the legend keys for the bars to my desired order (not alphabetical)?

Here a reproducible example:
plot_data <- structure(list(unit = c("AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA"
), group = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), varZ = c(0.315095655620098, 
8.47993358969688, 1.07286661490798, 0.451091277599335, -3.06214834600687, 
0.356725811958313, 2.84848970770836), varA = c(0.0098613808164373, 
0.641465996578336, 0.361015032231808, 0.213144088536501, 0.389915533736348, 
0.0736596005037427, 0.110731973079965), varC = c(0.341579372435808, 
0.330122645944357, 0.45065661072731, 0.092761187441647, 0.368695167452097, 
0.542871625348926, 0.563651240617037), varD = c(-0.00427791306283325, 
0.323448045179248, 0.017125289858086, 0.0177044845186174, 0.0418251685332507, 
0.0367124438518658, 0.0115989629644901), varB = c(-0.101550728082657, 
1.68335139006376, 0.36021358249709, -0.529840487614274, -0.199755599349737, 
0.260609032586217, 0.358311578631401), varE = c(0.0694835543632507, 
5.50154550075531, -0.116143900901079, 0.657321977615356, -3.66282860934734, 
-0.5571269325912, 1.80419590175152)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

## Split in two melted data tables. One with data for the stacked bars, one for the dots
bar_data <- plot_data[][, list(unit, group, varA, varB, varC, varD, varE)]
bar_data <- melt(bar_data, id.vars= c("unit", "group"))

line_data <- plot_data[][, list(unit, group, varZ)]
line_data <- melt(line_data, id.vars=c("unit", "group"))

p <-
  ggplot() +
  # Stacked bars
  geom_col( data = bar_data, 
            aes( y = value,
                 x = group,
                 fill = variable
            )
  ) +
  # Point
  geom_point( data = line_data,
              aes( y = value,
                   x = group,
                   colour = "Z"
              )
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.key.height = unit(.15,"cm"),
    legend.key.width = unit(.8,"cm"),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#005390", "#B6C5DE", "#082A4A", "#7AACF6", "#00B0F0"),
                    labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Z" = "black")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2))




You can achieve your desired result easily by working with one dataset which includes all categories and by converting variable to a factor. Then use a filtered dataset for each of the geoms, map variable on the color aes too in geom_point and finally apply the same scale to both the color and fill aes which could be achieved via the aesthetics= argument.
For the order of the categories in the legend. To arrange the categories rowwise you can set legend.byrow=TRUE and to achieve any desired order you can use the limits argument. For the latter case (but I would suggest that in general) use a named vector of colors and labels so that these are assigned to correct categories when changing the limits.
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

plot_data <- plot_data |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(!c(unit, group), names_to = "variable") |>
  dplyr::mutate(variable = factor(variable))

pal_color <- c("#005390", "#B6C5DE", "#082A4A", "#7AACF6", "#00B0F0", "black")
labels_color <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "Z")

names(pal_color) <- names(labels_color) <- levels(plot_data$variable)

p <- ggplot(mapping = aes(
  y = value,
  x = group
)) +
  geom_col(
    data = dplyr::filter(plot_data, variable != "varZ"),
    aes(
      fill = variable
    )
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = dplyr::filter(plot_data, variable == "varZ"),
    aes(
      color = variable
    )
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.key.height = unit(.15, "cm"),
    legend.key.width = unit(.8, "cm"),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title = element_blank()
  ) 

p +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = pal_color,
    labels = labels_color,
    aesthetics = c("color", "fill"),
    guide = guide_legend(ncol = 2, theme = theme(legend.byrow = TRUE))
  )



p +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = pal_color,
    labels = labels_color,
    aesthetics = c("color", "fill"),
    guide = guide_legend(ncol = 2),
    limits = c("varD", "varE", "varZ", "varA", "varB", "varC")
  )



Many thanks! This works very well, except: in the line labels_color <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "Z"), how do I make sure that the label "A" corresponds to "varA", "B" corresponds to "varB", etc? I understand this just depends on how the data is sorted, so depending on how it is sorted, label "A" could end up being assigned to a different variable than "varA"

@stefan you don't need all that part with tidyverse. Just reshape plot_data with data <- melt(plot_data, id.vars=c("unit", "group")) at the beginning. Then feed geom_col with data[variable != "varZ"] and geom_point with data[variable == "varZ"]. It makes the solution cleaner and easier to reuse. (upvoted btw!)

answering my own question: to make sure the labelling corresponds to the correct variables, I declare the factor levels as suggested by Elliot and then ensure to use the same order in the labeling, i.e. plot_data[, variable := factor(variable, levels=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "Z"))] and then labels_color <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "Z")

Just change colour to fill in geom_point and change the shape.
Couple of notes:

I added show.legend = FALSE in geom_point to avoid to show points on each label of the legend. If you try to remove it, you'll know what I mean.
I edited scale_fill_manual to add Z and 'black'

Like this:
ggplot() +
  # Stacked bars
  geom_col( data = bar_data, 
            aes( y = value,
                 x = group,
                 fill = variable
            )
  ) +
  # Point
  geom_point( data = line_data,
              aes( y = value,
                   x = group,
                   fill = "Z"
              ), shape = 20, size = 3, show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.key.height = unit(.15,"cm"),
    legend.key.width = unit(.8,"cm"),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#005390", "#B6C5DE", "#082A4A", "#7AACF6", "#00B0F0", "black"),
                    labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "Z")
  ) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2))



EDIT: building on the accepted solution I'll leave here a very similar code but based on data.table only. Also, I wrote a different guide_legend input because the one in the accepted solution wasn't working on my machine.
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

data <- melt(plot_data, id.vars = c("unit", "group"))

ggplot() +
  # Stacked bars
  geom_col( 
    data = data[variable != "varZ"], 
    aes(y = value,
        x = group,
        fill = variable)
  ) +
  # Point
  geom_point(
    data = data[variable == "varZ"],
    aes(y = value,
        x = group,
        colour = variable)
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.key.height = unit(.15,"cm"),
    legend.key.width = unit(.8,"cm"),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("#005390", "#B6C5DE", "#082A4A", "#7AACF6", "#00B0F0", "black"),
    labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "Z"),
    aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"),
    guide = guide_legend(ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  )



Many thanks! However, I still have three issues: 1) with your code, Z now appears together with the other keys, but with a white (invisible) box, rather than black as in your picture. 2) Any way to show Z with a point, as in the graph, rather than a bar? 3) Why is the legend ordered vertically, rather than horizontally? (i.e. B should appear at the right of A, not below it, and so on)

I don't understand the first issue. Did you copy my code? specifically the scale_fill_manual part? Note that I remove the scale_colour_manual. The second issue I'm not sure is solvable. I need to check. For the third one, I left the order as you did in your picture. What's your desired order?

I did copy your data exactly, but Z shows with a white box instead of a black one. What I mean with the order is that it should go left to right, not top to bottom.

To rearrange the items in your legend, it is easier to just reorder the factors before you make your plot. For your example, you can do this with a simple line of code such as:
bar_data$variable <-factor(bar_data$variable, levels=c('varE', 'varC', 'varA','varB', 'varD'))
In terms of merging the dot and the colors for your plot, this can be tricky when using two variable types (but generally can be worked around). If Z is the sum of the treatments (and therefore different to variables A-E) I would be tempted not to put it in the legend at all (as its technically not equivalent to the other letters) and instead to explain what the black dots are in the caption below the figure.
If i'm incorrect, and Z is equivalent to the other letters, then maybe consider adding it to the same bar_data dataframe, and plotting it in a uniform way.

You are correct (Z is the sum of the other variables). What you suggest could be an option. However, I would still be very interested in the tricky solution to add it to the same legend box as the bars. How can that be done?

A base R solution:
cols <- c("#005390", "#B6C5DE", "#082A4A", "#7AACF6", "#00B0F0")

plot_data.neg <- plot_data.pos <- plot_data[,c(2,4:8)]
plot_data.pos[,2:6][plot_data[,4:8] <0] <- 0
plot_data.neg[,2:6][plot_data[,4:8]>=0] <- 0

ylim <- c(min(colSums(plot_data.neg[,2:6])) * 1.15, 
          max(colSums(plot_data.pos[,2:6])) * 1.15)

par(mar=c(3,2,1,1), las=1)
bp <- barplot(cbind(varE, varD, varC, varB, varA)~group, 
              data=plot_data.pos,
              ylim=ylim,
              legend.text=c("Z", LETTERS[5:1]),
              args.legend=list(x="topright", nc=2, box.lty=0,
                               fill=c(cols, NA),
                               border=NA, 
                               pch=c(rep(NA, 5), 21),
                               pt.bg="red", col="black"),
              col=rev(cols),
              axis.lty = 1
)

barplot(cbind(varE, varD, varC, varB, varA)~group, 
        data=plot_data.neg,
        ylim=rev(ylim),
        col=rev(cols),
        add=TRUE
)

points(bp, plot_data$varZ, pch=21, bg="red", col="black")



(you have an amazing understanding of base R plots! congrats!) however, something looks wrong: bars A D E  should be partially positive and negative but they stand only on one side. Indeed Z, which is the sum, it's not on top of A and D or at the bottom of E.

@Edo Could be - I did this really quickly. I’ll double check when I've got more time …
